# win32 api for Process.BeginOutputReadLine

Tags: winapi

i wanted to know the c++ equivalent of c#'s Process.BeginOutputReadLine, where i aynchronously read from the standardoutput of another process. Is there any API for it?

Answer (score 1):

To read the standard output of a process you need to assign an appropriate handle to an instance of [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms686331) passed to [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms682425). Remember to include the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag.

Usually an anonymous pipe is used, created via [`CreatePipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365152.aspx).

See "[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms682499)" for an example.

You can use the normal Win32 approaches (OVERLAPPED + event, IOCompleteion Port,...) to reading the output handle asynchronously.